# How do I handle table that generates values dynamically using Web Driver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

**Problem:** How do I find the value from the table column and depending upon that value how do I select the adjacent checkbox.

**Description:** The table consist of 8 column. The first column (Column name is 'Select') consist of checkboxes. On last column (column name is 'Amount')
we have amounts. I want web driver to click on checkbox when the adjacent amount column consists of the value (let's say) 3380. 
(Means if particular amount is present in amount section then click on check box associated with that amount row)

[image]

**Note:** The values are dynamic in nature.

**HTML Code:**

```
<table width="760" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="../images/bground_title_row.gif" height="25">
<tr valign="top"><td>
<table width="760" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<div align="center"><span class="noninputtextfields">Select</span></div>
<td height="25" width="50"><div align="center"><span class="noninputtextfields">Select</span></div></td>
<td height="25" width="50">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Date</span></td>
<td height="25" width="150">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Handler</span></td>           
<td height="25" width="100">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Payee</span></td>
<td height="25" width="50" valign="center" nowrap="">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Ind</span></td>
<td height="25" width="210" valign="center">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Claim/Claimant</span></td>
<td height="25" width="100">&nbsp;<span class="noninputtextfields">Insured</span></td>
<td height="25" width="50"><div align="right"><span class="noninputtextfields">Amount €</span>&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="bulk_CHKpayment" value="0" onclick="this.checked=false;></td>
<td height="25" nowrap="">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">01/03/2017 08:40:41</span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">Peter Collins </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FirstName </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">N </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FL </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FirstName</span></td>
<td><div align="right"><span class="inputtextfields">5045.17&nbsp;</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="bulk_CHKpayment" value="0" onclick="this.checked=false;></td>
<td height="25" nowrap="">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">01/03/2017 08:40:41</span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">David Dessy </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FirstName </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">N </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FL </span></td>
<td height="25">&nbsp;<span class="inputtextfields">FirstName</span></td>
<td><div align="right"><span class="inputtextfields">1000&nbsp;</span></div></td>
<tr>
.
.
.
</table>
```

Comment: I can't find any checkbox with value 100000, can you just share the code of those checkbox and few (2-5) lines around that and remove the unnecessary code?

Comment: Please visit: http://tinypic.com/r/987b61/9

Comment: I want to select checkbox only if amount column has value equal to 100000

Comment: Akki there is unnecessary HTML code in the question, I am asking you to remove that so people can understand your question better, and you have higher chances of getting your answer.

Comment: Hello Gaurang, the added code is required. It seems big because the entire data is in table structure

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I would try

```
topElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@width=760][@cellspacing=1])[2]/tbody"));

List<WebElement> potentialElements = topElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@value,'100000')]"));

if (potentialElements.size() > 0) {
    //You have caught your fish
}
```

It is much more efficient to let Selenium do the search once vs. finding each element and testing its value in a loop.

**EDIT**

Problem Statement: I want to select the checkbox from 'Select' column if there is an 'amount'which is equal to 100000 in associated an 'amount' column.

```
public void checkPaymentItemsEqualTo100k() throws InterruptedException{
    topElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[@width=760][@cellspacing=1])[2]/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> potentialElements = topElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@value,'100000')]"));

    if (potentialElements.size() > 0) {
        for (WebElement x: potentialElements) {

             WebElement grandParent = x.findElement(By.xpath("/../../..");
             WebElement wElement = grandParent.findElement(By.xpath("/td[1]/div/input[@name='bulk_CHKpayment'])[1]"));
             if(wElement.getAttribute("onclick") == null){
                 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                 executor.executeScript ("arguments[0].click();" , wElement);
                 Log.info("Payment Item equal to 100k Amount is available");
                 sleepResponsibly(2000);
             }  
        }
    }
}

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Caveat: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please write an entire function for me? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: If you must sleep then sleep responsibly.

Comment: What grandParent does here?

Comment: I have used above method and still, it's not doing what it suppose to do. But Mike you are pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

it easier to do with xpath. 
Actual Xpath might differ as I haven't got a change to test. But the idea is you find the matching TD with text and then go to parent element, which is ROW and then first td and then input.

```
public void selectValue(String value){
    String xpath =  "//td[contains(text(),'"+value+"')]/../td[1]/input";
    WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    checkbox.click();

}
```